# Creating type from slices

Tags: go, slice

I want to create a data type which acts like a stack. I want to add and remove entries at the "top", as well as being able to print it out. In this example an XPath type for traversing an xml document and keeping track of the current path.

So I created a type xPath []string, and write the appropriate functions, ie: push() pop() and String().

My problem here is that the type loses its state, which baffles me a bit since I thought slices were reference types. Also if I try changing my functions into pointer receivers I run into several compile errors. At this point just to get by the problem, I simply changed []string into a struct with a single []string field. Though it still bathers me that I can't make it work with just a slice as the underlying type.

What is the correct way to do this?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

type xPath []string

func (xp xPath) push(entry string) {
    xp = append(xp, entry)
}

func (xp xPath) String() string {
    sb := strings.Builder{}
    sb.WriteString("/")
    sb.WriteString(strings.Join(xp, "/"))
    return sb.String()
}

func main() {
    xp := xPath{}
    xp.push("rss")
    xp.push("channel")
    xp.push("items")
    fmt.Println(xp)

    // Output: /
    // Wanted: /rss/channel/items
}
```

Comment: The push method doesn't have a pointer receiver, so xp in the method is a copy of xp in main. Assigning to that copy has no effect on the caller because you are simply overwriting the copy. Use a pointer receiver instead.

Comment: @Mikkel the `String` method seems unnecessarily over-engineered, the `strings.Builder` is intended for when you actually have something to build, not for concatenating two strings together. So it's quite unlikely it will provide any performance benefit over `return "/" + strings.Join(xp, "/")`, in fact it might be slower.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your push function is doing nothing.

Correct push function:

```golang
func (xp *xPath) push(entry string) {
    *xp = append(*xp, entry)
}
```

Slices are reference types in cases where you want to change their values (e.g. using indexes).

On the other hand, if you want to reassign them and replace the whole slice, you should use pointers.

---

Also about the stack, the are some better approaches:
have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28541609/looking-for-reasonable-stack-implementation-in-golang).